# Terminate all excel.exe process in Task Manager - Python

Tags: python

I want to terminate all 'excel.exe' in Windows task manager using Python... How to do that ?

My PC is window10 x64

Comment: Why exactly did you add the Python Tag? Do you want to let a python script terminate all excel.exe processes?

Comment: Yes bro... I want to use python code to kill all excel.exe in task manager

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried doing and what exactly didn't work yet?

Comment: Hi Bro.. I'm finding the answer ^^. I have tried to search on google but not found the correct answer

Comment: @HaDoan - don't assume gender and use 'bro' in your comments - We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion — and those are just a few examples. Use stated pronouns (when known). When in doubt, don't use language that might offend or alienate.

Comment: Thanks you! I will take note this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil):

```py
import psutil

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == "excel.exe":
        proc.kill()
```